# Object.keys not response in the Ionic APP

Tags: typescript, object, ionic-framework

I was using the Object.keys to push all my object’s key into the array, it test well in the browser ( Ionic serve --lab), but after ionic cordova build, Object.keys just return a empty array to me, and it seems very weird.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eqzj.png)

As you can see the Object.keys only return an empty array which expect to return a two length array.

Even I use the for…in or Object.entires function, still no any return, so confused…

I don’t think this is the tsconfig.json problem because I had edit the lib property

```
"lib": ["es2018", "dom", "es2017.object"]
```

Can anyone help to figure out how to fixed this problem ?